# How to avoid redirect in a spring webflow?

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I ended up using a lot of redirects in my spring web flow controller classes. I want to bring the number of redirects down.

```
return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(DUMMYFLOW_URL, true));
```

Currently I am using the above piece of code whenever I want to move to another state(Problem is there is a lot of corner cases and the clients can hit the web flow url from a number of states so depending upon the state I am doing a redirect ). How can I do a dispatch instead of sending a 301 ?